# z-index to ignore max height and always come on top

Tags: css

[image]

In the image above, list of blocks has a maximum height with `overflow-y: scoll`. However, when the more icon is clicked, I want the dropdown to come over everything and ignore the max height of parent div.

Is it possible with css?

Comment: What happened when you gave it highest z-index?

Comment: Nothing happens. It still get cuts down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your popup is likely an absolutely positioned element, and absolutely positioned elements are children to their nearest non-static (relative or absolute) positioned parent. If that parent has an `overflow: hidden/scroll/whatever` style on it it's going to cut off the child element regardless of what you set the child's `z-index` to.

You need to remove `position: relative/absolute` from the scrollable parent div and put it on the next grandparent div, then the child element won't be affected by the parent div's `overflow` style, however you may have to change your positioning calculations for the child if its parent has changed.

Relevant article [here](http://front-back.com/how-to-make-absolute-positioned-elements-overlap-their-overflow-hidden-parent).